# ValueUpdate to change my default viewModel value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

**ViewModel:**

```
define(['knockout',], function (ko) {
    return {
        Host: ko.observable("http://www.example.com")
    };
});
```

**View:**

```
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: Host, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
```

The above successfully shows me the "host" value and I can change the input. But the input value becomes pretty useless as the host value in my viewModel is still the default value example.com

How can I override this default value with my valueUpdate?

**PathService.js**

```
 var servicesPath = config.companyPath;
 var webRoot = config.Host;
 var companyRoot = webRoot;

    function setCompanyHost(url) {
        webRoot = url;
    }

    function setCompanyHost(url) {
        companyRoot = url;
    }

    function setServicesPath(path) {
        servicesPath = path;
    }

    function getCompanySegment(companyName) {
        return new uri(companyRoot)
            .segment(servicesPath)
            .segment('companies')
            .segment(companyName);
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more. Its a little unclear

Comment: When I change the value in my input from www.example.com to www.anotherexample.com it needs to update the ViewModel value to www.anotherexample.com. At the moment my app still uses www.example.com regardless of what I put in the input box

Comment: Can you try `textInput` instead of `valueUpdate` + `value`. This was introduced in KO3.2. Also ideally it should work with your code. Can you share a fiddle or other place where we can debug it?

Comment: +1 for a JS fiddle example. Is there something else happening to your config object before you check for its host value? I think what you are describing is something that should work by default with a data binding. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lwgty4xt/4/. Altering the input and then asking the observable for its value via the button shows an updated string.

Comment: @NickDeFazio Your jsfiddle is spot on. I do have a view model to my input that isn't doing anything BUT I do have a servicepath.js file that builds the apis. It gets config.host, the default host at the moment. I've added this above.

Comment: @TomRudge thanks. Can you show how you are doing your application of bindings as well? I think I'm starting to see the issue. Are you including your ViewModel as a requireJS include in BOTH pathservice.js and another file where you are calling ko.applybindings?

Comment: It looks like the PathService.js file isn't setting the observable value.  If config.Host is an observable, and companyRoot = webRoot = config.Host, then setCompanyHost(url) {} should be companyRoot(url) not companyRoot = url.  The latter changes the variable to reference the url value, while companyRoot(url) is the same as calling config.Host(url), which sets the value on the observable to the url.  Also, it would be new uri(companyRoot()), since the observable value is needed, not the observable itself.